# Spark application on yarn stuck at toLocalIterator.toList

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a spark application that runs fine on master local. However, when I deploy it to my yarn cluster in client mode, it gets stuck at `.toLocalIterator.toList`. I see the following INFO message

```
INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 0
```

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was caused by `sparkSession` being initialized in the spark executor. But what is strange is I saw no error in the application logs. This is how I was monitoring the application logs

```
yarn logs -applicationId <app_id> | less
```

I was searching for "ERROR" and looking at "WARN" logs. None of the logs showed this was the underlying problem. I fetched the logs at different points to see if I can get anything useful from the application logs. The only thing I saw in them was

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
```

Curious to know why didn't I see the underlying sparkSession initialization in spar kexecutor in my spark application log?